# convert text from latin to Cyrillic aspx.net

Tags: asp.net

i need to convert text in my labels.
I do in following way:

```
           String s = Label47.Text;

s = s.Replace("S", "С").Replace("U", "У").Replace("P", "П").Replace("А", "А");
```

Expected values is: СУПА, but it give me letters in another language: Ð¦Ð£ÐŸA

Comment: Could someone tell me solution for this

Comment: Someone could help me???

Comment: it worked well out of the box for me by creating a simple / new asp.net webform project and putting your code in there, it might be an issue with the doc type and encoding you are using for your page / web application.

Comment: @DavidePiras I have in marcup charset="UTF-8" nothing else

Comment: I need to convert this in cyrilic

Comment: @DavidePiras I read label value from database, it write it in text file, in text file it give me incorrect letters, maybe some of this made problem,So i want to convert label in text file??

Comment: @DavidePiras yeah, I've tried, the problem is when is writting in text file, now what can I do here??

Comment: Solved,working in text file, but not work in .html file, need to be in html, please help me